# How can I keep this jQuery scroll event from firing constantly?

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like a navigation bar to stick (position:fixed) when it hits the top of the window. But I also want the element to go back to normal positioning if the user scrolls back up.

The following code makes the element stick, but as you scroll, the event keeps firing, causing the element to flash in and out. If I remove the 'else removeClass()', it's smooth (and stops flashing) but the element stays fixed after I scroll back up to the top. Thoughts?

Relevant CSS:

```
.fixed-object {
    width:100%;
    background-color:tomato;
}

.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
   $(window).scroll(function(){

    var elementDepth = $('.fixed-object').offset().top;
    var scrollDepth = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollDepth >= elementDepth) {
        $('.fixed-object').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('.fixed-object').removeClass('stick');
    }


});
```

Comment: can make a quick fiddle ?

Comment: i've never done one before, but I'll try.

Comment: till you make one , check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486131/make-a-div-to-return-to-its-original-position-when-scrolled-up/20486399#20486399

Comment: so from what i get if user scrolls to bottom the nav bar should have top:0 , and fixed position , else just keep it as last seen !! right ?

Comment: here's a fiddle. I commented out @arun's solution, but both are there. Neither of them are flashing like they were for me locally, but neither are returning the element to its original height either. http://jsfiddle.net/B6mPn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it as simple.....

Declare the `elementDepth` as `GLOBAL` variable... it will work

```
var elementDepth = $('.fixed-object').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollDepth = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollDepth >= elementDepth) {
        $('.fixed-object').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('.fixed-object').removeClass('stick');
    }
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AzJg4/3/)

Comment: bingo! why does that work, if you don't mind? --just curious :)

Comment: elementDepth was being recalculated everytime you scroll.  If there was any "jitter" in the reported values from the browser, voila, flickering element.  Using it as a global caused it to be calculated once and such no "jitter" can get in.